# Von Neumann mixed with Havard in modern CPU?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Modern CPUs (for a very wider range of "modern") use separate data- and instruction-caches. So at the core they (probably) have separate busses for data and instructions. Does that make the "core of the core" a havard architecture?
Are modern CPU a mix of Havard and von Neumann?

Comment: Does the *architecture*, the specification of the abstract machine, fix what happens after a write to a memory location to be the instruction location within the next few instruction executions?